# Join tables in sequelize

Tags: join, sequelize.js, query-builder

i am trying to fetch data from db by joining 4 tables. As sequelize is new for me, i couldn't can any one please help me to do this. Here is the query which has to be done in ORM sequelize.

```
select p.page_id,p.page_title,pt.page_type_id,pt.page_type_name,e.exam_id,e.exam_name,m.menu_id,m.name,p.is_published,p.created_date,p.status_id from el_pages as p join el_page_types as pt on pt.page_type_id=p.page_type_id join el_exams as e on e.exam_id=p.exam_id join el_menus as m on m.menu_id=p.menu_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define the `Model` and then use it to query for an `Instance` of the model (or an array of `Instance`s). The column names are inferred from the model definition, or you can specify them with `attributes`. Use `include` to join the other tables.

**Models**

```
/* Define `Models` for Page, PageType, Exam, and Menu and 
   create associations/relationships between them */

const PageType = sequelize.define(
  'page_type',
  { /* define fields */ },
  { /* define options */ }
);
module.exports = PageType;

const Exam = sequelize.define(
  'exam',
  { /* define fields */ },
  { /* define options */ }
);
module.exports = Exam;

const Menu = sequelize.define(
  'menu',
  { /* define fields */ },
  { /* define options */ }
);
module.exports = Menu;

// ...add additional Models

const Page = sequelize.define(
  'page',
  { /* define fields */ },
  { /* define options */ }
);
// add relationships to other models
Page.associate = (models) => {
  Page.belongsTo(models.PageType);
  Page.hasMany(models.Exam);
  Page.hasMany(models.Menu);
  // ...additional relationships
};
module.exports = Page;
```

**Query**

```
// Query using the following syntax
const pages = await Page.findAll({
  attributes : ['page_id', 'page_title', 'is_published', 'created_date', 'status_id'],
  include: [
    {
      model: PageType,
      attributes : ['page_type_name'],
    },
    {
      model: Exam,
      attributes : ['exam_id', 'exam_name'],
    },
    {
      model: Menu,
      attributes : ['name'],
    },
  ],
});
```